# Chrome Page Monitor equivalent for ipad

Tags: ipad, applications, url, monitoring

Is there an equivalent to Page Monitor or an app for iOS? Using ipad 4

Comment: It might be easier to get good answers if you don't expect other people to know what Chrome Page Monitor does and describe the required functionality in the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

*I presume you are referring to Page Monitor, the Chrome extension that monitors sites for changes.*

You can do this with [**Punchr**](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/punchr/id591960232?mt=8). This will monitor parts of web pages and send you a push notification when the page changes.

[image]